# Discern between UINavigation bar back button, and interactive pop swipe to go back?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I need to discern between the two methods of going back in iOS – tapping the back button in a navigation bar, and using the screen-edge pan to do so. I’d rather not implement a custom back button if possible.

How might I go about this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I’ve implemented `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, declared myself as that delegate, and set up a boolean value called `isPanningBack`. Then implemented this guy;

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> tc = navigationController.topViewController.transitionCoordinator;
    [tc notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        if (![context isCancelled]) {
            _isPanningBack = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

Then, implemented `viewDidDisappear:animated`:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!_isPanningBack) {
        // We can be sure that we used the chevron.
    } else {
        // We can be sure that we used the swipe.
    }
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, tried out the solution above but needed to know *before* `viewWillAppear` is called, I came up with the following solution to distinguish between pops that are triggered by the back button and those that are triggered by the interactive swipe back.

```
class SpendingCardContainedNavigationController: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    private var poppingFromSwipe = false

    override init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?) {
        super.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)
        delegate = self
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        // Prevents a known, albeit a rare, bug 
        guard viewControllers.count > 1 else { return false }
        poppingFromSwipe = true
        return true
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        if !poppingFromSwipe {
            viewController.doSomethingUseful()
        }
        poppingFromSwipe = false
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        viewController.doSomethingElseUseful()
    }
}
```

This method allows you perform an action on your `viewController` in `willShow` and `didShow`. You could even go so far as to subclass `UIViewController` and add an `isBeingDismissedInteractively` `var` and then check that in `viewWillAppear` along with `isBeingDismissed` or `isMovingFromParentViewController` but that's just going too far for me.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for other solutions, I used to check the state, but don't quote me on that

```
if self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.state == .began {
  // Gesture bagan 
}
```